# How to access a Windows shared drive/folder from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, samba

Specifically, what are the login credentials I need to provide?

Details: The machine I want to access is running Windows 7, and I'm sure the folder sharing is working as other Windows machines can access it. In Ubuntu, I can go to Places -> Network and i see the machine there and open it, when I try to view the shared folder it will prompt me for Username/Domain/Password.

Are these credentials supposed to be my login details on the other machine? My account there does not have a password though, should I leave it blank? I'm also not clear what "Domain" needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your login should indeed be your login on the remote machine.

There is no way to allow general access to your home folder over the network without a password.  If you want full access to your home folder, you *must* give your account a password. You can leave automatic login turned on if you simply don't want to type a password at startup.

You can, however, allow access to the `Public` directory in your home directory without requiring login. To do that, go to `Network and Sharing Center`⟶`Change advanced sharing settings`, turn on `Public folder sharing`, and turn off `Password protected sharing` (located under the `Advanced Sharing Options` section near the bottom).

The domain, if this isn't on an ActiveDirectory domain (which seems likely, since your account has no password), should be either blank or the word `WORKGROUP` in all caps.

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
sudo smbpasswd -a "username"
```

where "username" is the login username,
ex:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a abc
```

you will be asked for a password.
This will create the login id and the password that you need inorder to open the file on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess... but have you tried the user *guest*, *invitado* or whatever is the name of the windows guest user in your language?.